# Unable to change varchar column to date type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my **SQL Server 2017** database that contains a `varchar(10)` column whose values all conform precisely to `date`. Here are some sample values, but there are many more:

```
2014-06-30
2004-05-06
2014-06-30
2001-08-18
2004-05-06
2009-06-30
2001-08-18
2004-05-06
2009-06-30
2001-08-18
2004-05-06
```

I am trying to convert this column to a `date`:

```
alter table SourceTable1 alter column END_DATE date;
```

...but I always get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I have examined the data and 100% of the column values conform to the `date` type. How can I change the column to `date` type?

Comment: You very likely don't have a value that is a valid for the `date` data type. You might think you don't, but if you didn't then the query would work. This is just one reason why choosing the correct data type to start with is the correct choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a simple test and it worked:

```
create table #t (t varchar(10))
insert into #t values ('2001-08-18')

alter table #t alter column t date
```

Another with something that looks like date but it isn't (got the same `error` as you):

```
create table #tt (t varchar(10))
insert into #tt values ('2001-08-32')

alter table #tt alter column t date
```

For sure you have a row that contains a varchar(10) that is not convertable. You can find this values by using a select like this:

```
select try_cast(yourColumn as date) as tryCastyourColumn,  yourColumn
from Yourtable
where try_cast(yourColumn as date) is null
```

Comment: Exactly right! I fixed the offending dates and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with M. Kanarkowski that your examples seem fine, but you probably are missing something. Since you have the 2017 version, run this to check what's wrong:

```
select END_DATE
from SourceTable1 
where END_DATE is not null and try_convert(date,END_DATE) is null
```